# Java- Conversion of a file into a Byte array and vice-versa using java7

Tags: java, arrays, java-7

Please explain me by giving an example of the following syntax:

```
static byte[] readAllBytes(Path path)
static Path write(Path path, byte[] bytes, OpenOption... options)
```

I have a rough idea about path,bytes but OpenOption! So an example will be best.
The code is related to java 7.

Comment: Please provide some sample code which shows what you understand and what issues you have.

Comment: Are you asking what an `OpenOption` is? this could help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html, The `...` means you can add as many `OpenOptions` as needed.

Comment: These are static methods in class `java.nio.file.Files`. Read the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

Comment: I need to convert a file into byteArray and convert back to the original file using the byteArray. I know these codes can do the required work but I don't know how to apply? I read the Documentations but it didn't help. I need an example which shows how to use the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is such an example in the [Files class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write%28java.nio.file.Path,%20byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29).

```
 Path path = ...
 byte[] bytes = ...
 Files.write(path, bytes, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code example:

```
Path path = Paths.get(pathToFile);
byte[] bArray = new byte[0];
try {
    bArray = Files.readAllBytes(path);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```